# Acumatica customer portal report customization problems

Tags: portal, acumatica

The Acumatica Customer Portal has shopping cart capabilities and it links to a report for sales orders or quotes.  The report is SO641010.rpx.  And there's some problems I'm having with the formatting and presentation of the report that I could easily fix with by customizing the report.

However, I cannot figure out how Acumatica Customer Portal is selecting and rendering the report from the directory structure collection of rpx files.  If I put a modified report in either ReportsCustomized or ReportsDefault, I'm still unable to get the customer portal report print routine to use my modified rpx.

The Request Profiler clearly indicates I'm working with the correct report number, but it seems something unusual is happening with the way the portal grabs the report it's rendering.  I'm guessing it might be caching of some sorts or the ReportLaucher that's getting invoked?

Doug Potter

Answer (score 2):

Ok Dhiren Chhapgar and I just discussed the correct answer here.  And this applies to all custom reporting, not just portal report customization.  Once a report is customized, it winds up in the database under

select * from userreport where reportfilename =

If you are trying to modify a customization by changing the RPX ( in ReportsCustomized) and the system won't take your new report mods, just delete this record from the userreport table.  The next time you run the report, the system will pickup the modified report and drop a new record in the userreport table.

Doug Potter